# Display chatter new feed in custom site URL using salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites

I have created custom page and display the chatter new feeds on successfully. i want to be display this custom page with chatter feeds separately. so i created custom site for this custom page but i got only empty page.

kindly know suggestions.

custom page:
[image]

Error page:
[image]

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If you read through documentation of Visualforce you will see the note

> Chatter components are unavailable for Visualforce pages on Force.com sites

That explains it .You cannot get chatter feed working on the sites .